# concatenation of 2 non-context-free languages that is context-free but not regular

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I'm having today a test on formal language theory, and I've seen a question
about it I'm having hard time solving.
The question is:
Give an example of 2 languages, L,M which are non-context-free but LM(the concatenation) is a context-free language but not a regular language.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let $1$ denote the empty word. Let 
$$
S = \{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\},\quad T= 1 + \{c^{2^n}\mid n \geqslant 0\},\quad L = ST,\quad M = 1 + (c^* - T).
$$
Observe that 
$$c^* = T \cup M \subseteq (1+T)(1 + M) = TM$$
and hence $TM = c^*$.
Now the languages $L$ and $M$ are not context-free but $LM = Sc^*$ is context-free but not regular.

Comment: What is the meaning $1 + (c^* - T)$ and so on?

Comment: $+$ denotes union and $-$ set difference.